# How to determine Phase Angle of 16-QAM

Tags: modulation, phase, binary, qam

[image]

I am trying to figure out how the angles for the following input are obtained. For example, why is 0100 -105 degrees and not 45 degrees? Is there a specific method or do we estimate what the angle value is? Some additional info that might help:

I and Q : Logic 1 = +1 V, Logic 0 = -1V
I' and Q' : Logic 1 = 0.821 V, Logic 0 = 0.22 V

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: For the example `0 1 0 0`, we have Q = 0, Q' = 1 so the quadrature component is -0.179 V. We also have I = 0, I' = 0, so the in-phase component is -0.78 V. The magnitude of that should be 0.80, not 0.85. Can you double-check the I/Q and I'/Q' table at the bottom of your post?

Comment: @nanofarad the values I and Q : Logic 1 = +1 V, Logic 0 = -1V, and I' and Q' : Logic 1 = 0.821 V, Logic 0 = 0.22 V were obtained from the reference material we use in class. The instructor didn't inform us other possible values, that might be the reason why the magnitude values are off.